# RIP Douglas Trumbull, special effects wizard for 2001, Blade Runner, and more

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Douglas Trumbull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Trumbull) died on Monday.  He was a legendary special effects creator, who worked on  *2001: A Space Odyssey*, *Close Encounters of the Third Kind*, and *Blade Runner*, among other films—mostly from the 1960s through 1980s.  He was also a director later in his career, having directed *[Silent Running](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067756/)*.

Comment: Oh, man, I need to rewatch Silent Running! Fantastic film.